# Failed to load class via Composer

Tags: php, namespaces, fosuserbundle

I try to update doctrine schema via:

```
$ php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

And I keep getting:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught 
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to 
load class "FOSUserBundle" from namespace "App\FOS\UserBundle".
```

Kernel.php:

```
 <?php

 namespace App;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Kernel\MicroKernelTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel as BaseKernel;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollectionBuilder;

class Kernel extends BaseKernel
{
use MicroKernelTrait;

const CONFIG_EXTS = '.{php,xml,yaml,yml}';

public function getCacheDir()
{
    return $this->getProjectDir().'/var/cache/'.$this->environment;
}

public function getLogDir()
{
    return $this->getProjectDir().'/var/log';
}

public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
    );
    $contents = require $this->getProjectDir().'/config/bundles.php';
    foreach ($contents as $class => $envs) {
        if (isset($envs['all']) || isset($envs[$this->environment])) {
            yield new $class();
        }
    }
}
```

composer.json file:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/",
        "FOS\\": "vendor/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "test/"
    }
```

FOSUserBundle.php namespace is:

```
namespace FOS\UserBundle;
```

And doesn't working but namaspace App is working fine. 
I tried:

```
$ composer dump-autoload
```

What am I doing wrong? It still taking App namespace before FOS.

Comment: Can you try "new \FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle()". (begin with slash)

Comment: Yep that was the problem thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a slash.

```
$bundles = array(
    new \FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
);
```